# file_get_contents doesn't work with image WAMP php 5.3.13

Tags: php, image, wamp, file-get-contents

```
  echo file_get_contents("result.png");
```

allow_url_fopen = On

php 5.3.13 raw data

```
?PNG  \0\0\0 IHDR\0\0\02\0\0\0f\0\0\0? ?P\0\0?IDATx^?y?]?u??????Rk
```

```
r??\\?\"?l??]?W
```

php 5.2.6(work fine) raw data

```
?PNG  IHDR2f? ?P?IDATx^?y?]?u??????Rk
```

```
r??\?"?l??]?W
```

php 5.2.6  =>  php 5.3.13  
    =>\0 
\ => \ 
" => \"

so i removed \0  ,
replaced \\ with \ 
and \" with "      but it's doesn't solve the problem.

thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: What do you need to read the image with this function? Maybe depending on what you need, you can use another function.

Comment: @Fred Wuerges   for data URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [*magic*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) (you should disable that setting).